# Recursive feature elimination with cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, rfe

I don't know why with increasing number of features, the accuracy could decrease?

The following figure is the [example of sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py) which shows, if we use more than (the top) 3 features, we will not only improve the accuracy, but instead will decrease it[image: ![h]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGA0m.jpg)
Could anyone please explain or give some references?

Comment: It's called "the curse of dimensionality". Others have asked, see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41685/why-does-increasing-the-number-of-features-reduce-performance.

Also, the image (and article) aims to show the _optimal_ number of features (in this case to be 3).

Comment: Thank @Sam a lot. It was really helpful.